# vba Application.OnKey F3 press keyboard not function during write on the cell and cursor flashing

Tags: excel, vba

I create some code for test Press F3 on VBA Excel, the function is Application.OnKey
this method excel not working during write on the Cell and Cursor Flashing inside Cell, but work fine after pressing Enter

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.OnKey "{F3}", "MyMacro"
End Sub
```

I want this method work during cursor flashing

[image: Cursor flashing]

Answer (score 0):

To test pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> in Excel, this needs to be run only once:

```
Sub StartF3()
    Application.OnKey "{F3}", "MyMacro"
End Sub
```

Then it would always work, if <kbd>F3</kbd> is pressed, up to the moment the Excel worksheet is closed. If you want to stop it, run this:

```
Sub StopF3()
    Application.OnKey "{F3}", ""
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I want to inform you this method working after press Enter, not working during edit on cell, cursor falshing you can see the picture above

Comment: You can't run VBA code when a cell is in edit mode.

Comment: If the idea is to run the F3 code while editing the cell - it cannot be done, the cell is in edit mode, as mentioned by the comment by @EvR.